# Solrj for JDK 1.4

Tags: java, solrj, jdk1.4

Is there a version of Solrj built for the JDK 1.4?
I installed the latest release of Solr on a separate Tomcat instance, but I have to send requests via an application developed (and deployed) with JDK 1.4
The archive at http://www.us.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/
seems to contain only versions compliant with JDK5 or later

Comment: I don't envy you. JDK 1.4 is 10 years old an [has been end-of-life'd for  almost 4 years now](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-jsp-138567.html). You might get lucky with using Retroweaver/Retrotranslator or a similar tool. But don't forget to bring up the enormous risk associated with using obsolete, unsupported base technologies to your management.